# How can I one-hot encode data with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, one-hot-encoding

Suppose I have a dataset

```
sex    age hours
female 23  900
male   19  304
female 42  222
      ...
```

If I use np.loadtxt or np.genfromtxt I can use a converter as a way to assign values to each of the categorical data in the sex column. Is there a way to instead create a one-hot column during the loading process? If not, where should I look to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

With pandas, you can pass the category dtype (which loads in the column cheaply):

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", dtype={"sex": "category"})

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
      sex  age  hours
0  female   23    900
1    male   19    304
2  female   42    222

In [13]: df.dtypes
Out[13]:
sex      category
age         int64
hours       int64
dtype: object
```

---

Once you have a category you can use `get_dummies`:

```
In [21]: pd.get_dummies(df.sex)
Out[21]:
   female  male
0       1     0
1       0     1
2       1     0

In [22]: pd.get_dummies(df.sex.cat.codes)
Out[22]:
   0  1
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  1  0
```

Comment: The main reason why I asked for one-hot encoding was so that I could put this into keras. Does keras accept this and convert it into a one-hot vector?

Comment: @user184074 I _think_ so from briefly looking at the code, but you can always pull out the codes `df.sex.cat.codes`.

Comment: Use `pd.get_dummies()` instead

Comment: There isn't a way to read into get_dummies, to do efficiently you need to do this first. i.e. then do `pd.get_dummies(df.sex.cat.codes)`.

Comment: Nope. You don't need the second step. It's not required at all

Comment: @Nain you can't use get_dummies to read a csv! The question is "Is there a way to instead create a one-hot column during the loading process".

Comment: You again didn't get my point. You don't need this `pd.get_dummies(df.sex.cat.codes)` Of course, you can't read a CSV using `pd.get_dummies()`. I

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `pandas.get_dummies` function.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `genfromtxt` approach:

```
import numpy as np

def hot(s):
    rec = np.genfromtxt(s, dtype="i8,i4,i4", skip_header=1,
                        converters={0:{b'male':1<<32, b'female':1}.__getitem__})
    return rec.view(np.int32).reshape((-1, 4))

print(hot(<your_file_name>))
```

Explanation: I think converters are required to return a single value. In order to get two we give the first column a double width dtype and the view cast the resulting recarray.